# Maximo Anywhere Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: win.doc.getCSSCanvasContext is not a function at (compiled_code)

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

Uncaught Exception: Uncaught TypeError: win.doc.getCSSCanvasContext is not a function at (compiled_code)

Uncaught TypeError: win.doc.getCSSCanvasContext is not a function

I get above exception after adding a text control or button control to the list control. Here is my code please suggest.

```
   <list collapsible="true" hideEmpty="true" id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_list" label="Inspection Components" resource="totalWOAssetMeters" showHeader="true">
            <listItemTemplate cssClass=".mblListItem" id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_listItemTemplate_MeterList" layout="InspMeterList">
                <listtext id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_MeterList_metername" layoutInsertAt="item1" resourceAttribute="metername"/>   
                <listtext id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_MeterList_meterdesc" layoutInsertAt="item2" resourceAttribute="meterdesc"/>

                **<button label="Test" id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_MeterList_more" layoutInsertAt="button1" />**                                    

                <eventHandlers id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_listItemTemplate_MeterList_eventHandlers">
                    <eventHandler class="application.handlers.MetersListHandler" event="click" id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_listItemTemplate_MeterList_eventHandlers_click_setAssetResource" method="setAssetResource"/>
                </eventHandlers>                                                                        
            </listItemTemplate>     
            <eventHandlers id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_list_eventHandlers">
                <eventHandler class="application.com.Inspection.handlers.InspectionMetersListHandler" event="render" id="WorkExecution.TaskDetailView_totalWOAssetMeters_list_eventHandlers_render_hideOrShowAssetMeters" method="hideOrShowAssetMeters"/>
            </eventHandlers>            
        </list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug with the latest version of Chrome and Anywhere. Please open a PMR and we can sent you an iFix