# MaximoAnwhere-7.6 Android Apps Development

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We are developing MaximoAnwhere-7.6 android application using maximoAnwhere server source code but while trying to login to android environment can't able to login and there is no error. So i remove the server code android environment and i tried to recreate it and its login successfully. Now i want to know the below the issues,

1. how to re-generate apps features plugin eg: map,barcode scanner ...etc
2. while accesing workorder detail view from workorder list view, there is no response and keep on loading only. While checking the logs for android LOGCAT i am getting following error,

   Uncaught TypeError: win.doc.getCSSCanvasContext is not a function

note : i am getting the above error some of few screens.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error "Uncaught TypeError: win.doc.getCSSCanvasContext is not a function" has been addressed in a fix from IBM.   You can find another article on stackoverflow related to the same thing.  They can provide a fix to work around this.  That will alleviate the never-ending loading screen.

Comment: can you please give me link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643380/maximo-anywhere-uncaught-exception-uncaught-typeerror-win-doc-getcsscanvascont